# Generating sequence of $\cosh a\sqrt{z}$ (recurrence)

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, power-series

Let ($z\in\mathbb{C}$, $a\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$)
$$w=\cosh a\sqrt{z}=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{a^{2n}z^n}{(2n)!}.$$
Then $w$ satisfies the ODE
$$4zw''+2w'-a^2w.$$
So if $w=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_n(z-1)^n$, then
$$4z(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}+2(n+1)a_{n+1}-a^2a_n=0.$$
But I should have gotten "another" recurrence for $a_n$, namely
$$4(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}+2(2n+1)(n+1)a_{n+1}-a^2a_n=0$$
where $a_0=\cosh a$ and $a_1=a/2 \sinh a$.
Are these even equivalent? If so, how can I prove it? Or is there an error in my approach?

**How I got my recurrence:**
$$\begin{align}4z\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\sum_{n\ge 0}a_n(z-1)^n+2\frac{d}{dz}\sum_{n\ge 0}a_n(z-1)^n-a^2\sum_{n\ge 0}a_n(z-1)^n&=0\\
4z\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nn(n-1)(z-1)^{n-2}+2\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nn(z-1)^{n-1}-a^2\sum_{n\ge 0}a_n(z-1)^n&=0\\
4z\sum_{n\ge 2}a_nn(n-1)(z-1)^{n-2}+2\sum_{n\ge 1}a_nn(z-1)^{n-1}-a^2\sum_{n\ge 0}a_n(z-1)^n&=0\\
4z\sum_{n\ge 0}a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)(z-1)^n+2\sum_{n\ge 0}a_{n+1}(n+1)(z-1)^n-a^2\sum_{n\ge 0}a_n(z-1)^n&=0\\
\sum_{n\ge 0}(z-1)^n(4za_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)+2a_{n+1}(n+1)-a^2a_n)&=0\\
4za_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)+2a_{n+1}(n+1)-a^2a_n&=0\end{align}$$

Comment: @Gary This was copied directly from the source. The "second" recurrence really doesn't contain $z$ there (whether or not it is correct).

Comment: @Gary I know. But this is exactly was this question is about. I don't know whether the two recurrence relations are equivalent.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood it. You cannot have $z$ in the recurrence, because the coefficients should depend only on $n$ and $a$. You have to write $z=(z-1)+1$ after the 4th line of your derivation and collect the coefficients of $(z-1)^n$.

Comment: @Gary Should there also be $2(2n+1)(n+1)a_{n+1}$ instead of $2(n+1)a_{n+1}$? Which one is correct?

Comment: I believe you will end up with the correct version that was given to you.

Comment: To find for yourself which recurrence is wrong: write down the first 5 terms (say) and check the recurrence using those values.

Comment: Suggestion: Write the coefficient $z$ as $1 + (z - 1)$ at the second line and distribute, _then_ shift indices.